# Can't access object even though I know it has been created?

Tags: python, class, object

I am creating class instances by running a text file and slicing the words into a list, I am using white space as the split point.

I am then creating objects of the class Word based on the names in the array using this bit of code.

```
exec("%s = Word(title)" % (title))
```

I know the objects are being created as I have the object print upon initialization.

My problem is that if I try to access these objects I get:

```
blue.getWordName()    
NameError: global name 'blue' is not defined
```

I am really confused and have tried searching for answers but I'm not sure I am using the correct terminology.

I have figured out that I can use a dictionary to achieve my aim but I really want to understand class instances more.

Is there a law against creating classes on the fly from list items?

I did try to include all of the code but it wouldn't let me so I'll include what I think is most relevant:

```
class Word():
def __init__(self, name):
    print 'You have just created me and I\'m called ' + name
    self.name = name


if count > 0 and wordArray[count - 1] == 'is':
        title = wordArray[count]
        if title not in checkKeyWords():
            exec("%s = Word(title)" % (title)) #set class from list item.


            if word in verbArray:
                exec("%s.setWordType('verb')" % (title))
```

Eventually I call the below function which has been created and is spelled correctly, I have also made sure that 'blue' is definitely in the list.

```
blue.getWordName()
```

Comment: "Is there a law against creating classes on the fly from list items" -- no, but there should be a law against using `exec` except in life-threatening situations. If you want to learn about classes and instances, then refrain from using `exec`, or you'll only be learning its quirks instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I totally agree with the other answer, use dictionaries instead. If you want an answer to your problem, please make your example reproducible. A slightly adapted version of your code:

```
class Word():
  def __init__(self, name):
    print 'You have just created me and I\'m called ' + name
    self.name = name
    self.wordType = None
  def setWordType(self, type_string):
    print "Hey, and the method works!"
    self.wordType = type_string

wordArray = ["spam","ni", "is","blue"]
count = 3
if count > 0 and wordArray[count - 1] == 'is':
  title = wordArray[count]
  exec("%s = Word(title)" % (title)) #set class from list item.
  exec("%s.setWordType('verb')" % (title))
```

Works fine:

```
> python bla.py 
You have just created me and I'm called blue
Hey, and the method works!
```

It might be that you have your indentation messed up. You check that the title is no in a list of keywords (`if title not in checkKeyWords()`), and create the object only if that holds. Could be that you refer to the `blue` object somewhere in the code, while it was not created. But without a solid example, this is impossible to tell.

Comment: Yea I realize that you probably need the whole code, sorry about that I'll remember to make all my future code runnable. I still can't access the function so I'm gonna take a long hard look at the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay both of you solutions helped me a lot and I figured it all out now. It was a combination of things really but with you help I got there, thank a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this. `exec` is a **very** bad tool to solve this. A much better way to do this is for example:

```
words = {}

if count > 0 and wordArray[count - 1] == 'is':
        title = wordArray[count]
        if title not in checkKeyWords():
            words[title] = Word(title)

            if word in verbArray:
                words[title].setWordType('verb')
```

Then you would do your final check like this:

```
words["blue"].getWordName()
```

Comment: If you absolutely have to use a local variable for some reason, then  you can do ``vars()[title] = Word(title)`` - however, I agree, using a different data structure is a much better idea.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response and it is a much cleaner method, I a still getting this message tough: blue.name()    
NameError: name 'blue' is not defined

Comment: @bisonpower: That is correct, you should use `words["blue"].name()` now.

Comment: Okay that has changed something but it produces an error message that reads:  Word["blue"].name()    
TypeError: 'classobj' object is not subscriptable any thoughts there?

Comment: bisonpowers: I said `words`, not `Word`. Read what I wrote again above.

Comment: Yea I realized I misinterpreted your code, but all's working now cheers!